# Adding an outlined heart icon to symbolize a favorite, over an image, that gets filled when clicked and hover

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images, that users can click and make them their favorites.

How do I add an extra layer to the image, so it has an outlined heart icon in the corner, when hovered, gets filled with the outline color, and when clicked stays filled, because its now a favorite?

Comment: That you have tried? code please. To learn css-properties: z-index, position, opacity.

Comment: update your code here, so that we can help better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add and extra 'layer' to your image, use the wrapper/container and target that. e.g.

```
<div class="img-wrapper"><img src=""></div>
```

With this you can take advantage of :before and :after elements

```
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper:before {
  display: block;
  content: ""; /* you can have a font here for your icons */
  background-image: url(); /* or you could use a background image */
  position: absolute;
  width: icon height;
  height: icon height;
  top: XX;
  left: XX; /* or right */
  z-index: 1000; /* make sure it sits above your image */
}
```

To change the icon, use :hover on the wrapper and use JS to add a class when the user clicks the img

```
.img-wrapper:hover:before {
  content: "" /* change icon or */
  background: url"" /* image */
}

/* If user clicks on image, add active class that changes the icon to the liked version */
.img-wrapper.active {
  content: "" /* change icon or */
  background: url"" /* image */
}
```

Adding a class with jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/